# Search records by values containing given strings

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot

I have a collection:

```
_id: ObjectId("11313123qeqerq")
products: Array
    0: Object
        name: "ABC-123"
```

I want to write a Spring criteria query which could find me all the products having name containing ("ABC", "DEF")

Can anyone help me come up with a query? Something in the lines of:

```
query.addCriteria(where(products).elemMatch(where(name).in("ABC", "DEF"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Your method `in()` does check an exact equality.
You should use LIKE as in SQL.
In criteria it does translate as `like()`:

```java
criteria.add(Restrictions.disjunction()
    .add(Restrictions.like("name", "ABC", MatchMode.ANYWHERE))
    .add(Restrictions.like("name", "DEF", MatchMode.ANYWHERE))
);
```

The criterion does look for strings containing either ABC or DEF anywhere.
Use `ilike()` for a comparison non case-sensitive.